# How to assign a test-class to a suite from the test

Tags: testng

We have a recurring problem that we miss to put tests into our suites. Basically the way to add test-classes to the suite-definition is "the one extra thing that noone remembers". It really isn't very practical to have to update another file in order to get it working.

So, we would like to assign the testclass to a suite from the class itself to make it harder to forget (and possible to set with templates).

Is there some annotation that basically lets some "generator" to find the tests and build the testng.xml on the fly with suites? Perhaps something like the @Runwith(Suite.class) but from the test-class itself.

Comment: good question.. we may need try something like https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2017/09/29/building-dynamic-testng-suites/